# Excel: Check For Each Word In Cell For Match In Entire Column And Copy Matches To Another Column

Tags: excel, vba

I am unsure how I can do this. I need to be able to take a cell and search each word in that cell and check to see if that word is within a different column.

IF word in A1 is within B:B Then 
   copy word to C1
Next word

In this example all the words in A1 are searched within all cells in column B the words that match are copied to C1.

[image]

Comment: You'll likely need to read up on loops, arrays, and dictionaries to accomplish this. At least, this is how I would tackle the problem. You can also use SPLIT() to split each word at the spaces. Once you do this, come back with your some code you have written so we can help. A lot of users will note that SO isn't a code writing service. Instead it is a place to get help when you can figure out how to fix what you have written :).

Comment: Show me the code!! :P

Comment: Why does `Chicken` come first in `C1`?

Comment: Thank you for your comment Brandon. I will look into your suggestions and see what I come up with.